# Addings things to a story and how to deal with players who have issues with it

Tags: gm-techniques, problem-players

I am currently running a long, in-depth, story-focused campaign that has been going on for months and seems to be well-liked among my group. As you might imagine, creating a world that we play in for that long, I come up with lots of new ideas for characters, adventures, and even little things.

I spend a lot of time making sure everything in this incredibly intricate story is consistent, but, of course, I do make small errors from time to time and forget little details. One of my players has an incredible memory and often seems to remember me saying things months ago that I can't even remember. I have no reason to doubt he is lying to me.

That in-itself is fine (it's quite useful, actually), but the bigger problem is that things I add to the campaign cause problems.

Today, for example, I made (what I thought was just a little joke) that one of the NPC characters now speaks more languages than him. He said that's not possible because I (apparently) said some time ago that the his character spoke all the languages he could ever need. If I said such a thing, I suspect I didn't mean it quite so literally. Since that time I have indeed created one new ancient language for an upcoming adventure.

Now, I'm quite happy for his player to learn this one to, but the NPC who has it does so because it is an ancient language and they have 43 knowledge history and 25 linguistics: more than enough to understand it. His character has 0 history and 13 linguistics. He is personally offended by the whole incident.

The bigger problem: if I try and discuss the argument with him, he acts as if he didn't get upset at all which, in fairness, is difficult to prove because he tends to be more passive aggressive.

How can I go about making small changes like this one without it things crumbling? I know I am probably at fault here too.

Comment: Based on the several questions you're posting, it sounds like individual solutions to each question's problem --while useful-- probably won't resolve the fundamental causes. Perhaps you could [join us in chat some time](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) to discuss the situation more fluidly.

Comment: I agree, you're asking 3 questions which all boil down to "we game with an assclown, what do I do?"

Comment: I'm gonna say this is either a pretty specific situation and too localised or already generally covered by your question about how he's [undermining you as the DM](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/26232/1204) (which, in turn, appears to have been covered already). Definitely feel free to bring it up in chat, many of us will be willing to talk with you about it. I'm voting to close this particular question though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"Past performance is no guarantee of future success."**

In isolation, one solution is to assert, as truthfully as you're able, that your statements were as accurate as could be at the time you made them. It was true, before you 'uncovered' this ancient language that the fellow's PC knew 'all the languages he would ever need.' That's now not the case. Situations being fluid and all.

However, not taken in isolation, I suspect that this would only lead to an argument over the 'fairness' of this circumstance. If you feel like going down the rabbit-hole of what 'fairness' means in a game with an active GM, that might bear some fruit. Otherwise, smile, assert the statement made in the title of the post, and continue to run the game for the players not so invested in ego and discord.